# What does error mean? : "Forbidden (Referer checking failed - no Referer.):"

Tags: django, nginx

I have a website running, which appears to be working fine. Yet, now I've seen this error in the logs for the fist time.

```
Forbidden (Referer checking failed - no Referer.): /pointlocations/
[pid: 4143|app: 0|req: 148/295] 104.176.70.209 () {48 vars in 1043 bytes} [Wed Jul 26 19:49:35 2017] POST /pointlocations/?participant=A2TYLR23CHRULH&assignmentId=3P4MQ7TPPYF65ANAUBF8A3B38A0BB6 => generated 2737 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 403) 1 headers in 51 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

It happens when posting to `/pointlocations/`, but only for one specific person ( each `participant` is unique per account, so I know it's only one person, having this problem repeatedly. Over 500+ other `participant` have had no such problem/error.

What does this error mean, what is likely causing it and can I fix this?

Comment: Hoi Mitchell, have you been able to solve this? I am facing such a problem but cannot identify the reason. Could it be because of HTTPS/SSL issues?

Comment: @QCaron. Hey. I didn't purposefully solve it. I was working on another side of the application for a while, and it went away. I guess  it's related to what i was working on, which was, if i recall correctly CSRF tokens. Maybe this can help. https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/164. If you do figure it out, please post it as an answer. Good luck.

Comment: In my case, I had this problem with a POST web hook called by a payment platform. In production, using HTTPS, the very same error as you have was raised. It could be that you have to use the csrf_exempt decorator here. Is your view called from a third-party, e.g. by some other server/website?

Comment: @QCaron Yes, it is. It's being called by an Iframe hosted on AWS.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

TLDR: Try to use the [csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) decorator for your view:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def my_webhook(request):
    # Do some stuffs...

    # Return an HHTPResponse as Django expects a response from the view
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

**You should only do this when absolutely needed to avoid potential security flaws.**

More context:

I faced a similar problem while working on a web-hook called by a third-party which is a payment solution. The Django view for that web-hook is called by the third-party to notify us every time the payment status changes (goes from 'open' to 'paid' for example).

As the payment platform only provides a payment ID in the request POST, the CSRF check should not be performed. Django allows you to do this through the `csrf_exempt` decorator.

Comment: This happens with the native django admin views!

Comment: I am using session authentication, so using csrf_exempt is not the solution for me. what should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Django might fix the missing Referer error (as it's sent voluntarily by the client depending on [`Referrer-Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy)).

As of Django 4.0 ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#csrf)), the backend will first check the `Origin` header before falling back to the `Referer` header ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/#how-it-works)):

> 4. `CsrfViewMiddleware` verifies the Origin header, if provided by the browser, against the current host and the `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` setting. This provides protection against cross-subdomain attacks.
> 5. In addition, for HTTPS requests, if the `Origin` header isn’t provided, `CsrfViewMiddleware` performs strict referer checking. This means that even if a subdomain can set or modify cookies on your domain, it can’t force a user to post to your application since that request won’t come from your own exact domain.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was adding the `csrf_exempt` decorator but through another decorator of mine that conditionally adds the exemption depending on the current environment. That seemed to stop this specific decorator from working, however, for some reason.

###### Not Working:

```
@conditional_decorator(ISLOCALDEV, csrf.csrf_exempt, some_requirement)
def endpoint(request):
    ...
```

###### Working:

```
@csrf.csrf_exempt
@conditional_decorator(ISLOCALDEV, None, some_requirement)
def endpoint(request):
    ...
```