# Heroku app giving 503 service unavailable error on postman on hitting the django api

Tags: python, django, heroku, heroku-cli

I tried to deploy django app on heroku and on running the app through postman received the error as: 503 Service Unavailable.

Logs:

```
2019-03-24T09:48:32.793173+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-03-24 09:48:32 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2019-03-24T09:48:32.793191+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-03-24 09:48:32 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:25659 (4)
2019-03-24T09:48:32.793192+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-03-24 09:48:32 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-03-24T09:48:32.793194+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-03-24 09:48:32 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2019-03-24T09:48:32.868969+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-03-24 09:48:32 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2019-03-24T09:48:33.226325+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
2019-03-24T09:48:33.226366+00:00 app[web.1]:   """)
2019-03-24T09:48:33.314368+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
2019-03-24T09:48:33.314372+00:00 app[web.1]:   """)
2019-03-24T09:48:34.434383+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/admin/categoryform" host=appname.herokuapp.com request_id=c7c71191-ab20-47be-ad56-565854dc6008 fwd="103.87.57.16" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=485ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2019-03-24T09:48:34.431881+00:00 app[web.1]: Forbidden (Referer checking failed - no Referer.): /admin/categoryform
2019-03-24T09:48:34.432837+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.10.113.175 - - [24/Mar/2019:09:48:34 +0000] "POST /admin/categoryform HTTP/1.1" 403 3388 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.1.1"
```

Comment: In the Heroku dashboard is your application running or not? You can attempt to correct the stack error by following its advice as modifying your requirements.txt to psycopg2-binary this will correct the Postgres warning. I’m assuming this is free tier service the H13 error is a timeout, your application may be sleeping and can’t address the immediate API call, be sure you have run your application then reattempt the postman call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does error mean? : "Forbidden (Referer checking failed - no Referer.):"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45336262/what-does-error-mean-forbidden-referer-checking-failed-no-referer)